# Correlation coefficient in terms of standard units: intuition

Tags: statistics, regression, correlation, linear-regression

Correlation coefficient

$$r = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(x_i-\bar x)(y_i-\bar y)}{\sigma_x\cdot\sigma_y}$$

But for a given data point $x_i$ and predicted value $y_p$,

$$\frac{(y_p-\bar y)}{\sigma_y} = r\cdot\frac{(x_i-\bar x)}{\sigma_x}$$

This is very non intuitive.

If we consider $$\alpha = \frac{(x_i-\bar x)}{\sigma_x}$$

and $$\beta =\frac{(y_i-\bar y)}{\sigma_y} $$
How can the average of $\alpha.\beta$ be same as $\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$?

Comment: Surely you must have $E \alpha = E \beta = 0$?

Comment: @copper.hat yes. Was that a question or a hint for the solution? the answer to question is yes.

If it was hint, I didn't get it.